# Logical data: Operators and Expressions

Tags: c++

So I'm learning C++ and I'm doing a lab but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. So the lab is:
We need a number that: Is greater than or equal to zero and less than ten - or - its value multiplied by 2 is less than twenty and its value reduced by two is greater than minus 2 - or - its value reduced by one is greater than one and its value divided by 2 is less than ten - or - it is equal to 11. Write the condition is the form of expression accepted by the C++ language and assign its result to the answer variable. The problem I'm having is that whatever the input, my output is always true.

```
bool answer;
int value;

cout << "Enter a value: ";

cin >> value;

if ((10 > value > -1) || ((20 > (value * 2)) && ((value - 2) > -2)) || (((value - 1) > 1) && ((value / 2) < 10)) || (value == 11))
{
    answer = true;
}
    else {
    answer = false;
    }
    cout << (answer ? "THAT'S TRUE :)" : "THAT'S NOT TRUE :(") << endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: The way to approach problems like this is to break them down into easier parts, and do one part at a time. Start out by testing whether the value is greater than or equal to zero and less than ten. Get that working. Hint: `10 > value > -1` won't work.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. I don't know how I didn't notice that. :P

Comment: You've got a bunch of unneeded parentheses in your code. I realize that some of them are probably because your compiler tells you that you might not be smart enough to understand the code you've written, but there are many that just aren't needed. For example, when you have an expression like `a < 10 && 0 <= a` you don't have to decorate the two subexpressions with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `>` groups left-to-right, such that `10 > value > -1` is parsed as `(10 > value) > -1`; Expression `(10 > value)` gives either `true` or `false`, and both options `true > -1` and `false > -1` will always evaluate to `true`. So your complex condition `(10 > value > -1) || ....` will always give `true` (shortcut evaluation).

Write `(10 > value && value > -1)` instead.